# Changing Charset to utf8 for all the fields and tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

How should I use the `mysql` and `awk` to change the charset for all the fields and tables for a specific database? I did not include username or password, so for sure it will not work.

Should I run it as it is and wait or does it need to be modified to work with authentication?

```
mysql --database=dbname -B -N -e "SHOW TABLES" \
| awk '{print "SET foreign_key_checks = 0; ALTER TABLE", $1, "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; SET foreign_key_checks = 1; "}' \
| mysql --database=dbname &
```

Answer (score 1):

First backup the database. Sometimes character conversions can give unexpected results.

I have had good success using these instructions:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',  table_name, ' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;') INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/altertablesstatements.sql'
FROM
information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_schema='<database-name>'
AND table_collation != 'utf8' 
GROUP BY table_name;
```

Add disable foreign_key_checks to first line of sql.

```
echo 'SET foreign_key_checks = 0;' >> /tmp/altertablesstatements.sql
```

Import the changes

```
mysql DATABASE  < /tmp/altertablesstatements.sql
```

Converting Columns

```
SELECT CONCAT(  'ALTER TABLE <DATABASE>.', table_name,  ' CHANGE ',COLUMN_NAME,'  ',COLUMN_NAME,' ',COLUMN_TYPE,' CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci',
IF(IS_NULLABLE='NO',' NOT NULL;',' NULL;')) INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/altercolumnsstatements.sql'
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS AS tb
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =  '<DATABASE>'
AND character_set_name != 'utf8';
```

Add disable foreign_key_checks to first line of sql.

```
echo 'SET foreign_key_checks = 0;' >> /tmp/altercolumnsstatements.sql
```

Import the changes

```
mysql DATABASE  < /tmp/altercolumnsstatements.sql
```

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-change-all-columns-and-tables-collation-to-utf8_bin-in-mysql-601456761.html